# Appium testing automatization: locate element with @ref id in Android Studio

Tags: android, appium, element, ref, locate

I have the element in Android:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="-1"
    android:layout_height="-2">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@ref/0x7f0c007c"
        android:layout_width="-1"
        android:layout_height="-2"
        android:hint="@ref/0x7f060035"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="0x21" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

the name for `0x7f0c007c` is `password` inside the `ids.xml` file.

This `TextInputLayout` is in the `LoginActivity` which starts right after `SplashScreenActivity`.

This is my class for the test:

```
public class test02 {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        String apkpath = "C:\\Users\\0013498\\Desktop\\qa-XXX-2-2-4-2.apk";
        File app = new File(apkpath);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.XXX.XXX");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.XXX.XXX.SplashScreenActivity");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"),capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //int KEYCODE_BACK  Back key.   Constant Value: 4
    }

    @Test
    public void appiumExampleTest() throws Exception {
        //WebElement emailEV=driver.findElement(By.id("com.XXX.XXX:id/email"));
        //WebElement emailEV=driver.findElement(By.id("com.XXX.XXX.android:id/email"));
        WebElement emailEV=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']"));

        emailEV.sendKeys("@");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm simply trying to set a text using the id of the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

My problem is that my test is unable to locate the element, and I have tried this 3 ways:

```
WebElement emailEV=driver.findElement(By.id("com.XXX.XXX:id/email"));
WebElement emailEV=driver.findElement(By.id("com.XXX.XXX.android:id/email"));
WebElement emailEV=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']"));
```

but none of them works.

the error message is:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

I'm beginner on `automatization` testing with `Appium` & Android, and I'm a bit lost.

Please, any help?

Thx

EDIT:

as suggested in an answer to my question, i started using UI Automator Viewer. It is a .bat file located in the /sdk/tools folder.

I started an android emulator device and run the UI automator Viewer. Then, when clicked on Device Screenshot, i got the all the elements and their attributes.

That way i could see the correct id:

[image]

I finally used:

```
AndroidElement emailEV=driver.findElement(By.id("com.mobgen.interview.mobgeninterviewtest:id/email"));
    emailEV.setValue("@"); // although i'm stuck here now
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please add screen shot of the screen through UiAutomator?

Comment: as requested above please add view from inspector (either appium or UiAutomator) to be able to see how this element you try to interact with is visible for appium, maybe the id you try to use is not properly applied to it ergo is not visible for appium

Comment: actually, i read the 1st answer this morning and i hadnt used the UiAutimator, such a n00b here. I have started using it and i got the solution. i edit my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: element is the xpath=//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,"email")]

Step 2:public void click(String element) {
        WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        webElement.click();
        System.out.println("Click element: "+element+" index = "+index);

    }

Step 3:
public void elementSendText(String element,  String text) {
        WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
        webElement.sendKeys(text);

    }
```

Comment: click is working fine (so xpath is good) but sendKeys is throwing en error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

Comment: what are you passing in the text?

Comment: i call elementSendText(path, "@"); inside appiumExampleTest()

Comment: May I no the xpath u r using.

Comment: String path="//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,\"email\")]"; the same you posted

Comment: Please use the one which I gave u.